# Function not returning what I expect (more below)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dom, local-storage

I have a function that filters localStorage to return an array of objects.

```
function targetOneTask(id){
    let allTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.allTasks)
    return allTasks.filter(task => task.title === id)
}
```

It works fine if I hard code the title

```
let description = targetOneTask("title of task")
// [{
      title: "title of task"
   }]
```

But here, it returns an empty array, even tough title is a string and can be found in the array of objects.

```
let title = parent.querySelector('.taskTitle').textContent
let description = targetOneTask(title)
```

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it's in the localStorage? Any help appreciated!

Comment: `localStorage.allTasks` -> `localStorage.getItem('allTasks')`. Maybe you need to trim the spaces around the title you get from the DOM: `let title = parent....textContent.trim()`

Comment: Need to see how you are adding to the array and saving it. See how to create a [mcve]. Really not enough shown here to do much more than guess what issue is

Comment: use your debugger to see what happen in localStorage

Comment: Thank you so much, the .trim() solved it for me. I would have never figured this out by myself.

Comment: I'm going to recommend that you`JSON.parse` all of your `localStorage` once, then operate on an Object that you store back to `localStorage` using `JSON.stringify`, when necessary. Just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I have to trim the spaces, which was automatically inserted as it is a header.

```
let title = parent.querySelector('.taskTitle').textContent.trim()
let description = targetOneTask(title)
```